# How to fix getting an average from user input

Tags: java

The instructions are the following:

- Write a method called inputThenPrintSumAndAverage that does not have any parameters.
- The method should not return anything (void) and it needs to keep reading int numbers from the keyboard.
- When the user enters something that is not an int then it needs to print a message in the format "SUM = XX AVG = YY". XX represents the sum of all entered numbers of type int.
  YY represents the calculated average of all numbers of type long.

I've coded the following method but I keep getting the incorrect average. What can I change to get the correct average?

```
public static void inputThenPrintSumAndAverage(){
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int sum = 0, counter = 0;
        long average = 0L;
        while(true)        {

            boolean number = scanner.hasNextInt();
            if(!number)
            {
                counter++;
                break;
            }
            else {
                int digit = scanner.nextInt();
                sum += digit;
                counter++;
            }
        }
        average = sum / counter;
        System.out.println("SUM = " + sum + " AVG = " + average);
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean with "iincorrect average", can you give an example? Do you just mean that it is not a decimal number but a whole number (Because you are doing integer division)?

Comment: Also: Are you sure you should be doing `counter++;` in the block where you handle if the user didn't enter a number?

Comment: How can you know if the user inputted a long if you're scanning for ints?

Comment: Do you want point values? just convert either sum or counter to `Float` or `Double`, and do you need the counter in if block where user didn't entered a number?

Comment: Hi all, sorry for the vagueness. I am new to this! Let me explain: if the user inputs 1 2 3 4 5 a, the method should return a sum of 15 and an average of 3 but I get an average of 2. Each time I get an average of correct answer less one.

Comment: Thank you for your help everyone! I have made adjustments to my code based on your comments and my problem is solved. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `scanner.hasNextInt()` to read util a non-integer value is supplied as input:

```
public static void inputThenPrintSumAndAverage() {
  Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
  int number, sum = 0, counter = 0;
  long average = 0L;
  while (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
     number = scanner.nextInt();
     sum += number;
     counter++;
  }
  if(counter != 0){
     average = sum / counter;
  }
  System.out.println("SUM = " + sum + " AVG = " + average);
}
```

Note that you should check the value of `counter` to avoid a division by zero.
If you want the average to be in decimals, change the type of `average` to double: `double average;` and cast the division to double: `average = (double) sum / counter;`.

Answer (score 1):

The following should do:

```
        if(!number)
            break;
```

Your average is wrong because you are incrementing "counter" more than you should.

Of course in the end you are going to have to add one more `if` statement to make sure you are not attempting to divide by `counter` if the counter is zero.  In that case, an average is undefined.

Also, as others have pointed out in the comments, it is entirely unclear to us what you mean when you say "I keep getting the incorrect average", and we generally frown upon questions worded so vaguely.  But if by any chance a "correct average" for you means an average with decimals, then you should use a `double` instead of a `long` for your average, and you should cast your `counter` to `double` before dividing, so as to force a `double` division instead of a `long` division.

Comment: My apologies, I am new to this! Let me explain: if the user inputs 1 2 3 4 5 a, the method should return a sum of 15 and an average of 3 but I get an average of 2. Each time I get an average of correct answer less one.